# How much of a priority should my Priority missions be?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there time-limited objectives in the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53841/are-there-time-limited-objectives-in-the-game)

In previous games, except for one mission, the main story missions could wait while side quests were completed with little to no consequences.  Is that the case with Mass Effect 3? Obviously, completing side quests will increase Galactic Readiness, but does putting off Priority missions cost me more in the long run?  I found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54344/1351), but it only pertains to one particular Priority mission.

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54720/1351) is actually a lot closer to what I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Priority missions advance the story and can make side missions unavailable. Some side missions, however, will appear in your journal even though the required locations are not yet unlocked. Complete as many side missions as you can before doing priority missions.